# How does COM avoid deadlocks when 2 objects call into each other?

Tags: windows, multithreading, winapi, com

Let's say there are two apartment-threaded COM objects, located in different apartments.  Or maybe they're in different processes altogether.  If one object calls a method on another, which in turn calls a method back on the first object, how does COM prevent the whole thing from deadlocking?

Comment: in case apartment-thread - call implemented via send or post message to com window in another apartment and than wait for message responce. but until wait thread can receive incomming window messages - so handle incomming calls

Comment: So is it calling `PeekMessage` behind the scenes or something?

Comment: @user15284017 See [Understanding COM Apartments, Part I](https://www.codeguru.com/soap/understanding-com-apartments-part-i/) (scroll down about 1/4 of the way, after Figure 2)

Comment: If you are making at outgoing marshalled COM call on an STA (UI thread) to an object on another apartment/thread or process, COM will simply run a mini windows message pump (GetMessage + DispatchMessage) to allow incoming COM calls back onto the same thread.  Or as you alluded to in your comments, *"calling `PeekMessage` behind the scenes or something."*.

Comment: Also, the notion of "apartments" to describe marshalling between objects and threads is one of the worst metaphors to describe something technically complex.  Most of the classic COM books do very little to explain it well.

Comment: @sol How would *you* design a system where mutual communication between two parties will not necessitate mutual communication between two parties?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-cowaitformultiplehandles

Comment: Deleted my previous comments, which did not really pertain to the OP's problem.

Answer (score 2):

What you describe is called reentrancy.

The truth is that COM doesn’t do anything explicit to prevent reentrancy issues. It’s up to the implementer of each object to take precautions where needed, as applicable.

Funny enough, reentrancy in COM is far less common in real life than you would think. Object graphs in COM tend to be mostly trees, which do not exhibit reentrancy. When you have cycles it’s almost always because of objects exposing event-type functionality of some sort, typically Connection Points.

Event callbacks are very limited in scope and they trigger under the explicit control of each object’s code, so the programmer is able to easily time them so they occur at safe places (for example at/near the end of a method’s body after all the real work is done). This prevents serious reentrancy issues from developing.

But nothing stops you from coding something dangerous. For example, if an object triggers an event while its internal object state is inconsistent, all bets are off.

You mention deadlocks. Deadlocks require a locking mechanism of some sort (for example a Critical Section) and should be extremely rare to impossible in COM apartments for the reasons listed above. Any object that triggers an event while holding a lock is asking for serious trouble, and a deadlock is not the biggest of its worries: by virtue of being an STA object the reentrant call will run on the same thread, and it will be able to acquire the locks again and proceed right through, which means it’s very likely that the object will corrupt its internal state, cause a crash, or worse. Note that locks in an STA thread only make sense if the resources controlled by the lock are accessible to threads outside the object’s STA.

And finally, nothing in COM stops you from causing an infinite recursion loop and subsequent stack overflow either. For example, take two COM objects Obj1 and Obj2, with Obj2 implementing an event. We can have Obj1 call a pObj2->SomeMethod(…) which causes Obj2 to fire the event; then have obj1 listen (“sink”) to that event, and have that event handler call SomeMethod() again.

**UPDATE:**

*<sup>Profound thanks to Remy Lebeau for pointing to in his comment something I had forgotten to discuss, via a link to CodeGuru article [Understanding COM Apartments, Part I](https://www.codeguru.com/soap/understanding-com-apartments-part-i/). And in the process I also learned something new myself I should have known about.</sup>*

There is one aspect of reentrancy and locking to consider and that is what happens during inter-apartment calls (either STA<->STA, STA<->MTA, or even STA<->OutofProc). During an inter-apartment call the STA (caller's) thread needs to stall and wait for an answer to the call request; the response cannot (by definition) execute on the same thread. But it can't just fully block (e.g. WaitForSingleObject) waiting for the response because the thread needs to be able to respond and process not only potential callbacks to the original object, but also to callbacks to *any other* object inside of the same apartment. If it were to fully block, the COM infrastructure itself would be introducing the potential for a deadlock and you wouldn't even need a dependency cycle between objects. So the COM marshalling infrastructure uses a more complex form of Wait that can unblock for a few other situations (Hans Passat points to CoWaitForMultipleHandles which looks right to me but I don't know the infrastructure to that level). If an applicable callback occurs, the marshalling infrastructure will unblock and allow that call to enter the apartment and proceed.

This is a form of locking induced by the COM infrastructure itself, rather than one coded explicitly as part of the object's implementation, which is why I hadn't thought of bringing it up. So COM does in fact "do something to prevent deadlocks", but to prevent deadlock potentials induced by its own infrastructure.

The part that I hadn't consciously realized was that this mechanism is very selective. It only lets through COM calls that form part of the same causality chain, that is, a callback, a direct consequence of the call that the thread was waiting on. Other COM calls into the apartment have to queue up and wait for that call chain to conclude, and for the STA thread to return to the thread's message loop.<sup>1</sup>

*<sup>1</sup> It makes complete sense that it needs to be that way, but I don't think I ever realized it.*